# cordova in ubuntu Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:ository... null

Tags: android, linux, cordova, android-sdk-manager

I have been trying to use cordova in Linux Mint 18 and compatible with ubuntu.   So far I could install everthing and updating anything necesary but I have the following problems.

In the command line when I type "**sdkmanager list**"  this appear:

```
~/Documents/cordovaApps/hello $ sdkmanager list

Warning: Observed package id 'build-tools;27.0.3' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3' (Expected '/home/felipe/build-tools/27.0.3')

Warning: Observed package id 'emulator' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/emulator' (Expected '/home/felipe/emulator')

Warning: Observed package id 'extras;android;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository' (Expected '/home/felipe/extras/android/m2repository')

Warning: Observed package id 'extras;google;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository' (Expected '/home/felipe/extras/google/m2repository')

Warning: Observed package id 'patcher;v4' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/patcher/v4' (Expected '/home/felipe/patcher/v4')

Warning: Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/platform-tools' (Expected '/home/felipe/platform-tools')

Warning: Observed package id 'platforms;android-26' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-26' (Expected '/home/felipe/platforms/android-26')

Warning: Observed package id 'platforms;android-27' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-27' (Expected '/home/felipe/platforms/android-27')

Warning: Observed package id 'sources;android-27' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/sources/android-27' (Expected '/home/felipe/sources/android-27')

Warning: Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/tools' (Expected '/home/felipe/tools')

Warning: Observed package id 'build-tools;27.0.3' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3' (Expected '/home/felipe/build-tools/27.0.3')

Warning: Observed package id 'emulator' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/emulator' (Expected '/home/felipe/emulator')

Warning: Observed package id 'extras;android;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository' (Expected '/home/felipe/extras/android/m2repository')

Warning: Observed package id 'extras;google;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository' (Expected '/home/felipe/extras/google/m2repository')

Warning: Observed package id 'patcher;v4' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/patcher/v4' (Expected '/home/felipe/patcher/v4')

Warning: Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/platform-tools' (Expected '/home/felipe/platform-tools')

Warning: Observed package id 'platforms;android-26' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-26' (Expected '/home/felipe/platforms/android-26')

Warning: Observed package id 'platforms;android-27' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-27' (Expected '/home/felipe/platforms/android-27')

Warning: Observed package id 'sources;android-27' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/sources/android-27' (Expected '/home/felipe/sources/android-27')

Warning: Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/tools' (Expected '/home/felipe/tools')

**Warning: Failed to find package list**
```

Now, when I tried to create an  android virtual device this happen:

```
avdmanager create avd --force --name testAVD --abi google_apis/x86_64 --package 'system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64'

Warning: Observed package id 'build-tools;27.0.3' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3' (Expected '/home/felipe/build-tools/27.0.3')

Warning: Observed package id 'emulator' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/emulator' (Expected '/home/felipe/emulator')

Warning: Observed package id 'extras;android;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository' (Expected '/home/felipe/extras/android/m2repository')

Warning: Observed package id 'extras;google;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository' (Expected '/home/felipe/extras/google/m2repository')

Warning: Observed package id 'patcher;v4' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/patcher/v4' (Expected '/home/felipe/patcher/v4')

Warning: Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/platform-tools' (Expected '/home/felipe/platform-tools')

Warning: Observed package id 'platforms;android-26' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-26' (Expected '/home/felipe/platforms/android-26')

Warning: Observed package id 'platforms;android-27' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-27' (Expected '/home/felipe/platforms/android-27')

Warning: Observed package id 'sources;android-27' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/sources/android-27' (Expected '/home/felipe/sources/android-27')

Warning: Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/tools' (Expected '/home/felipe/tools')

Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:ository...       
null
```

Is it any way to solve this?